# Android ListFragment has perpetual loading bar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android development and I have been having a problem with one of my recent projects. I have a listfragment as part of an activity which works and loads the test information I put into it, however, there is a loading spinner that will not go away no matter what I try. Here is the image:
[Perpetual Loading Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLktm.png).
Here is My code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.projects.nick.pheme;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fragmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragtrans = fragmanager.beginTransaction();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //setting the home screen
    FragmentList listFrag = new FragmentList();
    fragtrans.add(R.id.FirstFragment, listFrag);
    fragtrans.commit();
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/primary_material_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/hometestdonotuse"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/hometestdonotuse"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/hometestdonotuse"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/FirstFragment"
            android:name="android.support.v4.app.ListFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

FragmentList.java

```
package com.projects.nick.pheme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FragmentList extends ListFragment{

private ArrayList<NewsCard> cardArray = new ArrayList<NewsCard>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    //TODO get rid of this and have the actual news articles show up
    NewsCard testCard = new NewsCard("Nick invents the best app ever", "Nick's Mom");
    NewsCard secondCard = new NewsCard("This is a test", "Nicks dad");
    cardArray.add(0,testCard);
    cardArray.add(1,secondCard);
    MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(context, cardArray);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;

}

}
```

list_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainAdapter.java

```
package com.projects.nick.pheme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsCard> {

public MainAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewsCard> elements) {
    super(context, 0, elements);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //get the data
    NewsCard card = getItem(position);
    // Check if view is being reused, otherwise inflate
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = 
LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_list, parent, false);
    }
    TextView cardSource = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.sourceArticle);
    TextView cardTitle = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleArticle);
    // populate the data into the template view using the data object
    cardSource.setText(card.getSource());
    cardTitle.setText(card.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}


}
```

The NewsCard Class is just a basic class that I am using to hold the information, it just has a constructor and has two accessor methods for the string arguments.

Please let me know if I am missing something or something is unclear; I am new to stackoverflow. Thank you!

Comment: You've got a `<fragment>` for a `ListFragment` in your layout. That would be where the unwanted `ProgressBar` is coming from. A `<fragment>` isn't meant as just a placeholder for a `Fragment` you load in your code. It will actually cause a `Fragment` instance to be loaded when the layout is inflated. If you want to handle the `Fragment`s strictly in your code, then change the `<fragment>` to a `<FrameLayout>` and remove the `name` attribute. Alternatively, if you don't need to transact that `Fragment` dynamically, change the `name` to your class's name, and get rid of the `FragmentTransaction`

Comment: Btw, if nothing else is going in that `<LinearLayout>` around the `<fragment>`, then it's kinda useless, and you can remove it.

Comment: That did the trick, Thank you!

Comment: Also it was useless so thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)

> You must use ListFragment.setListAdapter() to associate the list with an adapter. Do not directly call ListView.setAdapter() or else important initialization will be skipped.

In your `FragmentList` instead of calling:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

call

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Edit:
The other problem (I think) you have is adding two instances of `FragmentList`.

Instead of

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/FirstFragment"
            android:name="android.support.v4.app.ListFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

use:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FirstFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I replaced the call to setAdapter to setListAdapter, and it probably saved me from having trouble somewhere down the road, however the loading circle still persists.